# Getting a named export to work with redux

Tags: react-native, redux

[As described in this blog post](https://daveceddia.com/redux-connect-export/), named exports have an issue with accessing the redux store. Is this not possible at all, or can I do something to my component to allow it to remain as a named export and still access the redux store?

I changed the named export to a default export (and changed the imports) and my component is working and accessing redux state. I ask only because I want to keep my components coded to a unified standard, and I have everything else as named exports.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misreading what that post says.  There's nothing about named exports that prevents components from accessing the Redux store.

What it *is* saying is that this is a common pattern for writing connected components:

```js
// named export for the "plain" component
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {}

// default export for the "connected" wrapper
export default connect()(MyComponent)
```

Like any part of your codebase, you need to write import statements that match how variables were exported from the other file.  So, in this case, if you want to use the connected wrapper component, you need to do a default import: `import TheConnectedComponent from "./MyComponent"`.

However, it's also entirely fine to do this:

```js
// named export for the plain component
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {}

// ALSO a named export for the connected wrapper
export const ConnectedMyComponent = connect()(MyComponent);
```

In that case, your consuming file would then need to do `import {ConnectedMyComponent} from "./MyComponent"`.

So, it's not about "named exports working with Redux" - it's about making sure that you're importing and exporting variables in ways that match.